# Duplicate account?

Tags: support, users, sock-puppets

The question [How to make Solution Explorer return to its previous state after clearing search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991159/how-to-make-solution-explorer-return-to-its-previous-state-after-clearing-search) was created by user [stijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128384/stijn) and then edited by [Stijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247702/stijn).

Stijn is a member for 4 years 5 months, stijn for 4 years 11 months. Both have same amount of badges, but they are active in different tags.

Could that be the same user and thus violate the Stackoverflow terms? Or is it just a funny random circumstance?

Comment: Random circumstance. Usernames are not unique, there are [3346 users named Alex](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/147990/100-most-common-usernames).

Comment: Since when is having more than one account violate our terms?

Comment: They don't have the same number of badges. One has 48 different badges (100 total), the other has 49 different badges (90 total).

Comment: @AndrewMedico: yeah, not exactly the same, I know. I also said, they differ by their text.

Comment: I can assure you we're not the same person. I did chuckle when editing that question :)

Comment: @Stijn: ok, that's nice to hear it from you directly. On the other hand side, everyone who creates two accounts for abuse reasons would probably give that statement :-)

Comment: I'm tempted to change my display name to Stijn just to make a point.

Comment: It's ok, you can stop downvoting.

Comment: @ThomasW.,  No we don't :P

Comment: @Thomas don't take it hard, there's no rep points here and it only means people disagree with your view. (that both accounts are the same person)

Comment: Everyone on SO should just change their name to "Bruce".  It would be a lot less confusing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is just a coincidence. Usernames are not unique, and neither is the name Stijn.

There are, for example, [3346 users named Alex](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/147990/100-most-common-usernames) on Stack Overflow. Similarly, there are [40 users named Stijn](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/201944).

There is no reason to think these two users are related beyond their names.

Even if these *were* duplicate accounts, that would not be against the rules either. As long as the accounts don't do what you cannot do with just one account (vote yourself up, for example), then having more than one account is a-okay.

Comment: The terms of service don't say I am not allowed to upvote my own questions or answers.

Comment: @ThomasW.: *Any fraudulent, abusive, or otherwise illegal activity or any use of the Services or Content in violation of this Agreement may be grounds for termination of Subscriber’s right to Services or to access the Network.* Bypassing the voting system with a second account is considered voting fraud.

Comment: In my next life I want to be born as a native English speaker.

Comment: @ThomasW.: What makes you think I ever was? :-)

Comment: Don't feel too bad, @Thomas. Most native English speakers have difficulty with legal-ese.

Answer (score 4):

First, user names are not unique. (I see no fewer than six people using "Thomas W", for instance.)

Second, having multiple user accounts does not violate the Terms of Service. It's only when someone uses multiple accounts to get around some restriction (voting for their own posts, avoiding a suspension or posting ban, etc.) is when it is a problem.

So, unless you have some evidence of dirty tricks that you can forward to a Moderator to more fully investigate, you should probably just move on.